# perl : Delete Header and footer in pdf

Tags: perl

I want to remove PDF header, footer *i.e.* crop the header and footer from a document.

I'm using the script below however it has been running for a very long time (24 page PDF).

```
use strict; 
use warnings;
use PDF::API2; 

my $filename = shift || 'test.pdf';
my $oldpdf = PDF::API2->open($filename);
my $newpdf = PDF::API2->new;

for my $page_nb (1..$oldpdf->pages) { 
  my ($page, @cropdata);
  $page = $newpdf->importpage($oldpdf, $page_nb);
  $page->cropbox('480%','10%','50%','620%');  
}
```

Is this the correct approach?

Comment: How long is a long time?

Comment: The script take 15 mins...